# PHP - Read JS array in PHP

Tags: php, jquery, arrays

I have a very complicated array, and i want to convert it into a PHP valid array so i can loop through the values.

JS array:

```
$test = (       // Portraits
  {'image'=> 'http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7319/8993158058_f82968e61a_b.jpg', 'thumb'=> 'http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7319/8993158058_f82968e61a_t.jpg'},
  {'image'=> 'http://farm3.staticflickr.com/2891/8993155214_b8e091c625_b.jpg', 'thumb'=> 'http://farm3.staticflickr.com/2891/8993155214_b8e091c625_t.jpg'},
  {'image'=> 'http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7432/8993133146_d647438c55_b.jpg', 'thumb'=> 'http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7432/8993133146_d647438c55_t.jpg'});
```

**EDIT**

PHP loop: it should the image part for every value

```
  for ($i = 0;$i < $test.length;$i++){
    saveToDisk($test[$i]['image'],$i);
 }
```

Is the above correct? how can i read through the values?

Comment: if you swap `{` and `}` with `[` and `]` you hafve valid php short array notation, if you swap `=>` with `:` it looks like valid JSON.

Comment: @coder101 take a look at my answer, it's a working example on how you should do it. just make sure you `strinify` your Javascript object in order to be able to use json_decode on it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use json_decode function to convert json formatted string into a PHP arrays (or object if you're calling it without the second parameter or with false instead)

```
$test = '[{"image":"http:\/\/farm8.staticflickr.com\/7319\/8993158058_f82968e61a_b.jpg","thumb":"http:\/\/farm8.staticflickr.com\/7319\/8993158058_f82968e61a_t.jpg"},{"image":"http:\/\/farm3.staticflickr.com\/2891\/8993155214_b8e091c625_b.jpg","thumb":"http:\/\/farm3.staticflickr.com\/2891\/8993155214_b8e091c625_t.jpg"},{"image":"http:\/\/farm8.staticflickr.com\/7432\/8993133146_d647438c55_b.jpg","thumb":"http:\/\/farm8.staticflickr.com\/7432\/8993133146_d647438c55_t.jpg"}]';

$array = json_decode($test, 1);

// Looping each inner array and printing image/thumb keys
foreach ($array as $arr) {
   echo $arr['image'].' - '.$arr['thumb'];
}
```

Also in order to convert your JavaScript object to a valid JSON string you should be using the JSON.strngify function:

```
JSON.stringify(object); // <-- JavaScript function
```

Comment: that string isn't quite json

Comment: @kris You are right, that's because he's example wasn't in the correct json string format. I've edited my answer to show my example.

Comment: I've edited the question, how can i read the values of the `image` part  using the loop. Please help.

Comment: @coder101 , just make sure the string you are passing is using in valid JSON format (using the strinify function in JavaScript). and you will be able to use Json_decode to convert it into an PHP array.

Comment: your example doesn't really solve my problem. Can you show it with multiple values, also with the `thumb` part as i provided in the question?

Comment: @coder101 I've edited it like you've requested. please accept my answer.

Answer (score 0):

you can read parse in PHP using json_decode

Answer (score 0):

Your "array" code looks like an invalid mixture between PHP and Javascript syntax. It should look more like:

```
$test = json_decode("[
  {'image'=> 'http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7319/8993158058_f82968e61a_b.jpg', 'thumb'=> 'http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7319/8993158058_f82968e61a_t.jpg'},
  {'image'=> 'http://farm3.staticflickr.com/2891/8993155214_b8e091c625_b.jpg', 'thumb'=> 'http://farm3.staticflickr.com/2891/8993155214_b8e091c625_t.jpg'},
  {'image'=> 'http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7432/8993133146_d647438c55_b.jpg', 'thumb'=> 'http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7432/8993133146_d647438c55_t.jpg'}]");
```

Or better yet:

```
$test = [
  ['image'=> 'http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7319/8993158058_f82968e61a_b.jpg', 'thumb'=> 'http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7319/8993158058_f82968e61a_t.jpg'],
  ['image'=> 'http://farm3.staticflickr.com/2891/8993155214_b8e091c625_b.jpg', 'thumb'=> 'http://farm3.staticflickr.com/2891/8993155214_b8e091c625_t.jpg'],
  ['image'=> 'http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7432/8993133146_d647438c55_b.jpg', 'thumb'=> 'http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7432/8993133146_d647438c55_t.jpg']
];
```

Comment: How can i read the values through a `for` loop using the second version of the array syntax you provided?

Comment: @coder101 i've added a foreach statment in my answer